# Auto-find missing links in Indesign plugin

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

Any plugins for InDesign (CC) that would scan and search on all the folders in the computer and in the mounted drives on a Mac for a missing file?

Something that would keep us from searching that file (even if the path is included in the link details). That would be pretty useful for people working on multiple computers, and having some links on each computers.

Comment: Hi Marc, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it is far more a technical support question than a design question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a script or plugin for that.
Just go to the links window, look for the name of the missing file and search for it in the default operation system search engine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is actually what we are doing right now. I was thinking more about a plugin that would do the search within InDesign for you, instead of searching it manually by pasting the file name in the search box of the relink window. I was wondering if there was a faster way of doing it by using a plugin or something. Thanks again for your input!

Comment: There are several scripts out there that do the job e.g. http://kasyan.ho.com.ua/batch_update_links.html